# Java Swing errors =S AbsoluteConstraints

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, absolute, border-layout

```
public class Primary extends JFrame { 
    public Primary(String title) {
        super(title);
        JLabel Label1 = new JLabel("hello");
        Container c= getContentPane();
        c.add(Label1, new AbsoluteConstraints(117,15));
    }
}
```

I have written this code having invoked runnable `JFrame` in the main class.
However although no errors are showing, I'm getting lots of errors when trying to compile.
The error is long but here is a sample of it:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
        at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:426)
        at javax.swing.JRootPane$1.addLayoutComponent(JRootPane.java:531)
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1120)"
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** First of all i want to point it out that `BorderLayout` is the **default layout** for `JFrame`.

**-** And you need to **explicitly change** the `Layout` to be used, if you don't want the default `BorderLayout`.

**-** If possible use the `Group Layout` developed by `NetBeans` Team back in 2005, Its simply awesome. Use the `Windows Builder Pro` tool which is now freely available from Google.

Answer (score 2):

The default layout manager for a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`

Take a close look at the [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) API.

You need to change the layout manager to meet the requirements of the constraints (or the other way around)

Comment: Oh awesome. Sorry first time using GUI's just practicing really.

Comment: Can you tell me how I would go about doing this please?

Comment: Sorry, was running out the door, check out [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong, I think it would be beneficial for you to have a good read through the swing tuturials at oracle. In particular

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

and

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html